# elastic search converting and inserting lat lon as geo_point in bulk

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I have a simple `csv` file, that has 4 fields, serial_num,post_code, lat,lon  such as:

```
serial_num,post_code,LAT,LON
06AA209365,PE10 2AZ,532342,168459
98A819621,PE10 1AA,532342,168459
07FD490906,PE12 1VV,497882,157983
```

I need to bulk insert to `elasticsearch`. The lat lon fields need to be defined at a single geo_point field,  so I have created a mapping as follows:

- index is serial_data
- type is widget

  ```
  PUT /serial_data
  {
  "mappings": {
  "widget": {
    "properties": {
      "serial_number": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "post_code": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "location": {
        "type": "geo_point"
      }
    }
  }
  ```

  }
  }

I have tried to use `embulk` to insert the data, as I thought as I had a defined mapping.  If I defined the lat long as doubles or long, then `embulk` would resolve the lat, long into the single location, it doesnt and I was over optimistic.

I also thought that `embulk`had a bulk-input-json plugin, but I cannot locate it.

**Question**

Any ideas would be really appreciated on how to bulk load this data.

Answer (score 0):

I use tree filte plugins.

- embulk-filter-insert: insert location column
- embulk-filter-ruby_proc: combine LAT and LON column
- embulk-filter-column: remove LAT and LON column

data.csv

```
serial_num,post_code,LAT,LON
06AA209365,PE10 2AZ,532342,168459
98A819621,PE10 1AA,532342,168459
07FD490906,PE12 1VV,497882,157983
```

conf.yml

```
in:
  type: file
  path_prefix: data.csv
  parser:
    charset: UTF-8
    newline: CRLF
    type: csv
    delimiter: ','
    quote: '"'
    escape: '"'
    trim_if_not_quoted: false
    skip_header_lines: 1
    allow_extra_columns: false
    allow_optional_columns: false
    columns:
    - {name: serial_num, type: string}
    - {name: post_code, type: string}
    - {name: lat, type: long}
    - {name: lon, type: long}
filters:
  - type: insert
    column: 
      location: 
  - type: ruby_proc
    requires:
      - json
    columns:
      - name: location
        proc: |
          ->(_,record) do 
            return { lat: record["lat"], lon: record["lon"] }.to_json.to_s
          end
        skip_nil: false

  - type: column
    columns:
      - {name: serial_num}
      - {name: post_code}
      - {name: location}


out: {type: stdout}
```

output

```
+-------------------+------------------+-----------------------------+
| serial_num:string | post_code:string |             location:string |
+-------------------+------------------+-----------------------------+
|        06AA209365 |         PE10 2AZ | {"lat":532342,"lon":168459} |
|         98A819621 |         PE10 1AA | {"lat":532342,"lon":168459} |
|        07FD490906 |         PE12 1VV | {"lat":497882,"lon":157983} |
+-------------------+------------------+-----------------------------+
```